# Running ARM Assembly on an x86 processor?

Tags: assembly, x86, arm

How would someone go on running ARM Assembly on an x86 machine? Is getting an ARM based machine like a Raspberry Pi to run those programs better?

Extra Questions:

- Is Arm Assembly the same on all ARM processors or does it differ from one device to another?
- Does ARM have any substantial advantages over x86, Power and other processor architectures?

Comment: These are three very different questions, and should be asked in separate posts.

Comment: To run ARM machine code on a non-ARM machine, you need an emulator; QEMU is one such.  It will be tens to hundreds of times slower, so if you want to run at reasonable speed and not just for testing, you should get an actual ARM machine.  For more specific suggestions on emulators, cross-assemblers, etc, please specify the OS you are using on the x86 machine.

Comment: @NateEldredge I got an answer from Erik Eidt below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would someone go on running ARM Assembly on an x86 machine?

Using an emulator; some of these emulators translate to the other processor's machine code in bulk to speed emulation.  Some of these emulators also emulate system calls but there are many ARM-based systems...

> Is Arm Assembly the same on all ARM processors or does it differ from one device to another?

ARM is a family of processors with a long history of evolution.  ARM6, ARM7, ARM8, ARM9 are all instruction set architectures, each having multiple specific processors with varying tradeoffs in price, performance, and power consumption.

> Does ARM have any substantial advantages over x86, Power and other processor architectures?

Over the years, the ARM processors have traditionally had a power (saving) advantage over other processors.  To see why is too involved for this answer.  The intel x86 architecture, having widely variable length instructions, is more complicated to decode.